# Change default Sid, new Connection Dialog, oracle sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Ist there a way to change the default Sid "xe" which is Always used when adding a new Connection for "Oracle Sqldeveloper" ?

Comment: No, there's no way to change the defaults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.

But you can use an existing connection as a template.

Create a connection with your defaults.

Then, when it's time to create a new connection, edit your template, then save it with a NEW NAME. Presto-changeo, you have what you need/want.

Comment: Ok thats a good hint. I will have a try next time, thx